# styled-components: Dynamic css attributes based on other styles (margin based on font-size)

Tags: styled-components

I want to base my margin on the font-size of the component, so like that:

```
const H1 = styled.h1`
  font-size: ${props => props.theme.fontSizes.large + 'px'};
  margin: ${props => props.theme.fontSizes.large * 3 + 'px'};
`
```

However, I do not want to repeat the reference to the ThemeProvider theme prop in the margin, but I want to do something like that:

```
const H1 = styled.h1`
  font-size: ${props => props.theme.fontSizes.large + 'px'};
  margin: ${H1.styles['font-size'] * 3 + 'px'};
`
```

The reason why I want to do that is not only to avoid repeating myself, but also because in my design system I extend components several times, so it would be error prone to manually repeat the current component's font-size (that might come from some earlier extended components in a totally different file).

Any ideas how to elegantly solve this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, not super elegant, but works. I use the [`.attrs` constructor](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics#attaching-additional-props) which allows to manually pass props to the styled component:

```
const H1 = styled.h1.attrs({
  fontSize: props => props.theme.fontSizes.large
})`
  font-size: ${props => props.fontSize + 'px'};
  margin: ${props => props.fontSize * 3 + 'px'};
`
```

Or to look at a more complex example where the usefulness of this becomes more clear (when we define a component with a certain font-size, extend this component later on, and *then* add the margin that is based on the font-size from earlier):

```
const Heading = styled.h1.attrs({
  fontSize: props => props.theme.fontSizes.large
})`
  font-size: ${props => props.fontSize + 'px'};
`

const HeadingWithMargin = Heading.extend`
  margin: ${props => props.fontSize * 3 + 'px'}; // this extended component still has access to the passed props
`
```